# Not able to save registry key RESOURCEMAP

Tags: c++, registry

I'm capturing registry HKLM\Hardware using the function RegSaveKey() in Win32 application. I'm saving this hives in .CD file. I'm able to capture all other keys under HARDWARE key except RESOURCEMAP. I don't know why this subkey is not getting capture.

Here is my code :

```
  HKEY  hKeyToDump;
  RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "HARDWARE", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKeyToDump );  
  RegFlushKey(hKeyToDump);
  RegSaveKey(hKeyToDump, "<Path of .CD file>", NULL);
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

The `RESOURCEMAP` subkey is "volatile", its data are just kept in memory rather than kept backed up in a hive file. And according to its documentation, `RegSaveKey` is unable to save volatile keys.  My guess is that `RESOURCEMAP` was made volatile because it contains temporary device information, collected while the system is running and which can change each time the system is restarted.

Comment: Perfectly said. I was also thinking of that. But is there any other way to capture `RESOURCEMAP` ?

Comment: I would need to know more about how you use the saved registry data in order to think about possible solutions.  You can still read the keys and values under `RESOURCEMAP` using registry API functions like `RegEnumKeyEx`, `RegEnumValue` and `RegQueryValueEx`, but you would need to figure out how to save the returned data to a file in a format appropriate for your application.